# How to pass multiple grouped fields to a parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I feel like I've tried every solution in here but nothing is quite right.

I have a table shows a category, subcategory, and a person's name. Each category is totalled.

```
Category 1
      Subcategory 1
             Person 1
             Person 2
      Subcategory 2
             Person 1
      TOTAL: 3
```

This could be repeated again underneath for Category 2 with its own total.

I want to click on that total value and pass all this information to another page. If I click the "3", it should only apply to everything this total refers to. Just Category 1. But obviously it should send both those subcategories and all those people.

if I pass the parameters from this page through to the other page it will include all categories, not just those a given total refers to. If I pass a field value through it will only send the first of each and not all. For example, sending the Subcategory field through would only send Subcategory 1 and not both Subcategory 1 and 2.

I've tried using joins on these values to pass multiple parameters through but no luck.

Is there a trick to this I'm not realising or should I do something entirely different? Thank you.

Comment: Show us how you pass the joined values and tell us where you send them.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly then you probably don't need to pass multiple categories.

If let's say you original query looked something like

```
SELECT Category, Subcategory, person, someValue FROM myTable
```

Then when you when you click the total value you would only pass the category (Category 1)

In your subreport, the dataset query would then be something like...

```
SELECT Category, Subcategory, person, someValue FROM myTable
WHERE Category =@myCategoryParameter
```